# Windows Azure for podcast content

Tags: azure

I'm trying to evaluate the use of Windows Azure storage/media/cdn services to host the audio content for a podcast site, but I'm having some trouble figuring out what the best approach would be to do so. Do I need to setup a storage account and use blob storage with CDN enabled for the content? Would it be better to use media services? If the latter, I can't seem to find any good documentation on how to get started with the media services, or how to manage content. Anyone have any ideas on any of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Azure Media Services is currently in Preview, you will need to register for it on Azure Portal (Preview Section) via https://manage.windowsazure.com/, more info here:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/media-services/

Not sure if you need media services to be honest, if you create a storage account and then upload your files to a public blob container (set the cache expiry header otherwise it will expire from the cache 72 hours in the CDN), then you log into the Portal and enable the CDN on that storage account. All your content will be pushed to the CDN edge nodes.

The CDN will assign a URL in the form of http://.vo.msecnd.net. (Note it can take up to 60 minutes for DNS propagation to occur).

Maarten Balliauw has an excellent blog post explaining it all: 
http://acloudyplace.com/2012/04/using-the-windows-azure-content-delivery-network/

HTH

Comment: Sounds like just using storage with CDN enabled seems to be the way to go. Thanks for the link to the article, very useful. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your requirement you really need to use Azure Storage for your content. Making your Azure Storage a CDN endpoint, is a decision content owner make based on how the content will be consume. As you are trying to store content for podcast, you sure can take advantage of CDN due to the nature of podcast as public service. So Having a Azure CDN service would be the best for you.

Before you decided to choose Windows Azure Media Service I would suggest to take a look [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/media-services/) to learn how it works technically and weather you really need all of this. Windows Azure Media Service is end to end work flow for media content providers to encode, protect, distribute, stream to multiple devices. It may be something very big for your project and honestly not needed.

As you are just trying to provide audio content to podcast users, uploading encoded content to Azure Storage and then distribute to your users over CDN would be the best. If you would need to compress it then you may need a WebRole to do it.  IF you need content in any of these specific area, please suggest and we sure can help.

Comment: I wondered if Media Services was overkill...thanks for confirming that for me. I mostly just wondered if it provided any advantages due to the fact that I was wanting to serve up media type content with it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Yes Media service will sure be overkill for your project because the scope of your project.